# Narita 8 Hour Layover

Tags: layovers, nightlife, nrt

My return flight from Phuket gives me an 8 hour layover at 10:50 pm in Narita Aiport.  Any recommendations for nearby activities?

Comment: In the middle of the night? I suggest a few hours of sleep, if you can.

Comment: Narita is a very old city and not too tiny. I'm sure it has izakayas like anywhere else in Japan. I don't think it has very much at all that caters to a non-Japanese crowd. So it might depend what you're looking for.

Comment: We can't suggest anything because we have no idea what you'd be interested in. Stack Exchange isn't the right place for questions like this (see the [help centre](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)).

Comment: Thanks. I am interested in cultural, sightseeing and shopping options.